# respetar espacios en variable que pasa a una url

Tags: laravel, ajax

tengo el siguiente problema que no me doy idea como podría resolver: Tengo en mi controlador una función que recibe un parámetro (llamado: ubicacion), en mi vista blade mediante ajax obtengo el valor de ese parámetro y lo paso a un link  , me funciona ya que si inspecciono veo que la ruta con el parametro es la correcta, el problema esta en que hay muchas de estas "ubicaciones" del tipo: Laboratorio 1, Bilioteca Primer Piso (con espacios) y eso me produce error en la url ya que
en el navegador al pinchar el enlace me muestra la url asi: **127.0.0.1:8000/informe/ubicación/Laboratorio&%1/** cuando debria ser asi: **127.0.0.1:8000/informe/ubicacion/Laboratorio 1/.**

En la vista, en el codigo ajax lo tengo asi para generar el enlace:

```
var ubicaciones = '<a href="/informe/ubicacion/'+response.ubicacion+'">Generar Reporte</a>'
```

y la funcion en el controlador es basica:

```
public function informe($ubicacion){
//codigo de la funcion
}
```

Agradecido de antemano de cualquier comentario

Answer (score 0):

Las urls no permiten espacios ni caracteres especiales como acentos y otros, la forma más corta es usar slugs que se encarga de generar una url limpia, pero te trae un problema ya que puede haber un: Example Lab: 1 o Lab- 1
con slugs obtendría la misma respuesta de lab-1 en amabos casos, ya que los caracteres especiales y los espacios se traducen a "-", que es un estándar en las URL limpias, para corregir esto asigna dos campos, uno "url" y otro "nombre" donde la URL es única